# How to get RelativeLayout from current Fragment in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to get the `Relativelayout`'s color of the current Fragment when `Viewpager` changes.

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    Fragment fragment = padapter.getItem(position);
                    View view_ = fragment.getView();

                            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)view_.findViewWithTag("rLayout");

                    }
                });

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F20C36"
    android:tag="rLayout"
     >


</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#3EF20C"
    android:tag="rLayout"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

and so on... These are xml files of Fragments.

I gave the tag "rLayout" to `RelativeLayout` in xml file. Program gives the error in the line that I get the `RelativeLayout`. Isn't this the correct way to get `RelativeLayout` from that `Fragment`?

Comment: Please post your xml too. I normally find views by id and it works without issue.

Comment: please paste the exception